# Starting node js service on local

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a node js gradle application. I am not sure how to run the application locally.

I have done gradle build (./gradlew) and npm run build(compile). All my dependencies are in the `node_modules`.

I have a server.ts file having server code apart from the routing.

My package.json-

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "..",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async-child-process": "^1.1.1",
    ..
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/handlebars": "^4.0.36",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.45",
    "@types/pg-types": "^1.11.4"
  }
}
```

How to run the project on the server.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build/js/",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration":true,
        "target": "es2015"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/main/ts/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @MarS Updated with package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js will not run ts code. after build it'll js code in dist directory(depends on tsconf.json).

In package.json add below code, run `npm run serve` to start server.

or go to dist dir and run `node server.js`.

I have created a sample on GitHub [check here](https://github.com/rsharma0011/NodeTypescript)

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "npm run build && npm run start",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "build": "tsc"
}
```

Comment: added tsconfig in my question. There is no dist folder present

Comment: @themaster check the link